# I want to replace all the filenames in a folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to replace filenames in a folder using PowerShell.
 I tried with this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem L:\PowerShell
Write-Host $files
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $newFileName=$file.Name.Replace("Flow","SOF")   
    Rename-Item $file $newFileName
}
```

Lets say, I have three files (.txt) and named `First-One-Flow`,`Second-One-Flow` and `Third-One-Flow` in a folder called PowerShell. I want to replace that "Flow" with "SOF".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the below code :

```
Get-ChildItem L:\PowerShell | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "Flow","SOF" }
```

You can pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem` directly into `Rename-Item` so there is no need to put it inside of a `foreach` loop.